# How can I generate .rst files from python classes without automodule?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

suppose, I have a python project which has some packages and some classes inside those packages.

I want to generate .rst files mirroring each module and each class. I want intermediate .rst files that could be compiled into HTML files.

how can I do that without using automodule?

my aim is to see how a python package or class looks like in .rst fotmat.

Comment: Are you looking for a library recommendation?

Comment: @metatoaster, i am actually trying to hand-code rst files. so, I need sphinx command to do that. no library recommendation.

Comment: As StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service, please edit the code of your honest attempt to solve this problem into your question as a [mre]

Comment: Isnt the docstring already valid rst, so you only have to extract the docstring and paste it into an rst file? The only thing that would be different are the documentation for arguments and return values, but you probably write some custom roles that emulate the ones that autodoc provides.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html