# Generate static/complete `.rst` files with autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

is there a way to make `sphinx-apidoc` (by using the `autodoc` extension) generate fully static `.rst` files with the complete documentation content (docstrings) directly embedded in them?

For example, given a `foo.py` module with one fuction:

```py
# foo.py
def add_one(a: int) -> int:
    """Some documentation.
    """
    return a + 1
```

currently the `foo.rst` file it produces is:

```
foo module
==========

.. automodule:: foo
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Can we somehow get a complete static `.rst` so that e.g. you can copy the docs in a different directory, and run `make html` without the need to import the python code?

Thank you!

Comment: autodoc (Sphinx extension) does not generate .rst files. Files such as foo.rst can be generated by `sphinx-apidoc` (command-line tool).

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19523151/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67396151/407651

Comment: There is no way to make sphinx-apidoc generate complete .rst files. It can only be used to generate "stub files" with `automodule` directives in them.